# Why do I have this result: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, melt

[image]

```
sub4 = sub4.melt(id_vars = 'Sort_order','year'
                           ,var_name= 'sex'
                           ,value_name= "International_migrant_stock_at_mid-year")
```

I try to melt the dataframe to separate sex and migrant stock.
I think my codes look fine but it just keeps giving me the syntax error.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I try to melt the dataframe to separate sex and migrant stock.
I think my codes look fine but it just keeps giving me the syntax error.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You are missing the required `frame` argument.

Answer (score 0):

need [ ] for id_vars

```
sub4 = sub4.melt(
    id_vars=['Sort_order', 'year'], 
    var_name='sex',
    value_name="International_migrant_stock_at_mid-year"
)
```